# How can I obtain an Active Directory Group name from a SQL Server stored SID?

Tags: sql-server, security, powershell, active-directory, sql-server-2000

This is a follow-up of a question I asked earlier this morning ([posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830695/how-can-i-query-an-which-active-directory-account-is-associated-with-a-sql-server/6831153#6831153).)  Following the instructions provided, I've managed to query my SQL Server 2000 database for a SID associated with an AD Group.  The SID, however, looks like this:

```
0x0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567
```

What can I do to obtain the name of the AD Group referenced by the SID?  I've tried googling PowerShell scripts, however, most of their examples of SIDs look like this:

```
S-1-5-21-1454471165-1004335555-1606985555-5555
```

Obviously, that doesn't look like the value I'm getting back from the SQL Server.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using sqlps (SQL Powershell host) which works against SQL 2000 (I've tested this on my 2000 instance) you can use this:

```
$query = @"
select sid from syslogins where isntgroup = 1
AND name = 'CONTOSO\mylogin'
"@

invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "myserver" -Database master -Query $query | 
foreach {$SID = new-object security.principal.securityidentifier($_.SID,0); $SID.translate([system.security.principal.NTAccount]) }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those without sqlps:
use this online C# shell do format single sid to text

http://rextester.com/AFAC13570

code backup:

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static string ConvertByteToStringSid(Byte[] sidBytes)
        {

            StringBuilder strSid = new StringBuilder();
            strSid.Append("S-");

            // Add SID revision.
            strSid.Append(sidBytes[0].ToString());
            // Next six bytes are SID authority value.
            if (sidBytes[6] != 0 || sidBytes[5] != 0)
            {
                string strAuth = String.Format
                ("0x{0:2x}{1:2x}{2:2x}{3:2x}{4:2x}{5:2x}",
                (Int16)sidBytes[1],
                (Int16)sidBytes[2],
                (Int16)sidBytes[3],
                (Int16)sidBytes[4],
                (Int16)sidBytes[5],
                (Int16)sidBytes[6]);
                strSid.Append("-");
                strSid.Append(strAuth);
            }
            else
            {
                Int64 iVal = (Int32)(sidBytes[1]) +
                (Int32)(sidBytes[2] << 8) +
                (Int32)(sidBytes[3] << 16) +
                (Int32)(sidBytes[4] << 24);
                strSid.Append("-");
                strSid.Append(iVal.ToString());
            }

            // Get sub authority count...
            int iSubCount = Convert.ToInt32(sidBytes[7]);
            int idxAuth = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < iSubCount; i++)
            {
                idxAuth = 8 + i * 4;

                if (idxAuth >= sidBytes.Length)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("OK :old NT account");
                    return strSid.ToString();
                }

                UInt32 iSubAuth = BitConverter.ToUInt32(sidBytes, idxAuth);
                strSid.Append("-");
                strSid.Append(iSubAuth.ToString());
            }
            return strSid.ToString();
        } 

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine(
                ConvertByteToStringSid(
                    SoapHexBinary.Parse(
                        "0x01050000000000051500000079542007311FAE6D096510145E540300".Substring(2)
                    ).Value
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

credits:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1322822.aspx

[How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)