# What is SID in SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What is SID? How this is interrelated with the user logins ? What is the functionality of the SID ? Can anybody explain it with simple words?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403629.aspx

Answer (score 4):

From Wikipedia's entry on [Security Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier):

> In the context of the Microsoft Windows NT line of operating systems,
>   a Security Identifier (commonly abbreviated SID) is a unique name (an
>   alphanumeric character string) which is assigned by a Windows Domain
>   controller during the log on process that is used to identify a
>   subject, such as a user or a group of users in a network of NT/2000
>   systems.

Comment: as sid in sql is stored in fancy way - use this to format it correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831933/how-can-i-obtain-an-active-directory-group-name-from-a-sql-server-stored-sid/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking about SIDs in the context of SQL, not within AD.