# How to check SQL Server SID vs Active Directory SID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am having an issue logging into a **SQL Server 2000** Database via Windows Authentication, where access has been granted at the database level via an Active Directory group, to which the user in question is a member of.

I can check the user's AD group membership via: whoami /groups and see:

```
somedomain\SalesDB-RO                   Group            S-1-5-21-2172273820-3134075794-738947201-31792  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group             
somedomain\SalesDB-RO                   Group            S-1-5-21-923798017-1667202166-518595180-7612    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
```

Due (somehow) to the nature of Active Directory SID History, there are two entries.

Now, I can look in the database (using SSMS, using another account) and see that 'SalesDB-RO' does in fact have db_datareader permissions in the database, yet the user still cannot login.  I'm wondering if perhaps the 'SalesDB-RO' group is textually the same, but perhaps has a different SID within the SQL Server database.

How would I view the SID assigned to the 'SalesDB-RO' group within the SQL Server?  (I do not personally have SysAdmin privileges, but could get someone that does to execute any necessary commands).

Secondary question:
On another SQL Server (2008) instance where I do have sysadmin rights, I see SID's are of the form:

```
0x0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567
```

....whereas from AD they are in the form:

```
S-1-5-21-2172273820-3134075794-738947201-31792
```

Is there a way to get comparable versions of the SID's?

### UPDATE

As it turns out the issue was the user was a member of an Active Directory Group that was DENIED read permissions on the database.

Comment: It's not exactly answering your question, but you're trying to troubleshoot why an AD group can't access a db. Have you checked to see that the AD group is set to be a security group (as opposed to a distribution group)? I know that's tripped me up before.

Comment: @Ben: It seems to be working for other people (including myself) so don't think that's the issue

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831933/how-can-i-obtain-an-active-directory-group-name-from-a-sql-server-stored-sid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, in my case the issue was the user was a member of an Active Directory Group that was DENIED read permissions on the database.

Better (more relevant to the question) info here (credit @Kodak):

[How can I obtain an Active Directory Group name from a SQL Server stored SID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831933/how-can-i-obtain-an-active-directory-group-name-from-a-sql-server-stored-sid/)